# Debugging local Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, debugging, build-dependencies

I want to debug a foreign project, that I have cloned from GitHub, so that I have it as a local project. It's a UI library without a main class, so it can't be executed by itself.
Instead, I created a new Maven project and added that library as a dependency in Netbeans:

[image]

That seems to work.

Now, if I set some breakpoints in **that library** and run **my new project** in debug mode, the debugger doesn't stop on the breakpoints.
Also, when I declare some logger outputs in that library, they are not executed.

Is there any way to debug a local project, that I can only add as a dependency?

**Update:**

I changed the details in the POM of the library, to be sure, I'm referencing the local dependency:

```
<groupId>org.primefacesLocal</groupId>
<artifactId>primefacesLocal</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I built the project again and I can find it in my local repo.

I added this into the POM of my new project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefacesLocal</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefacesLocal</artifactId>
    <version>9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I use intelliJ, never had any problems debugging a dependency library. Maybe there are no source files present?

Comment: You say you "can only add as a dependency", yet you say you "declared some logger outputs in that library". How did you add logging to the library if it's only a dependency?

Comment: @Kayaman: I have cloned that library, so I have it as a local project. But I can't instantiate or run it directly. So my solution was to add that library as a dependency to an new project and run that.

Comment: Is the source of the library used to set breakpoints based on a source JAR from your local maven (as it should be), or from decompiling? If the latter, try to load Maven sources

Comment: After chaning the downloaded code - did you build it and create a new artifact in your local maven repository?

Comment: @Simon: In its POM it says: `<packaging>jar</packaging>`. Does it help?

Comment: @user1170330 have you checked your repo if the project is there? have you updated your dependency to a snapshot version?

Comment: @Stultuske: Please see my update.

Comment: how and where do you add the breakpoints?

Comment: `<packaging>jar</packaging>` isn't relevant. In IntelliJ, check Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing , flag 'Automatically download: sources'

Comment: @Simon he's using NetBeans, not IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks, @Stultuske, missed that. For NetBeans right-click on Libraries and select Download All Library Sources. Also, as this is a local repo, you'll need to *generate the sources using maven-source-plugin*. Searching for 'generate sources maven locally' should give you what you need there.